# How to force Gradle to use Java 11

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I am using Ubuntu on a new laptop.  I have downloaded java 11 and Gradle-6.6.1 per my instructors instructions.  Java 8 has never been downloaded. When compiling the instructors example code, the compile fails for var types and a Network class.  We believe Gradle is using java 8.  I can not figure out how to get Gradle to use 11.  Here are the instructions I followed for downloading both..

wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Then unpack the tar file with:
tar zxvf openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

I moved the unpacked file into a different folder:
sudo mv jdk-11 /opt/

And removed the tar
rm openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Open vim to edit env variables:
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/java.sh

Copy into the file and :wq
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

Next time you login to your console
java -version
javac -version
GRADLE (info (Links to an external site.))

Or download and install:

To download gradle (example gradle 6.6.1 -- please check on this page for the version you should install):

wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip

To unzip:
unzip gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip
I moved the unpacked file into a different folder (could have also moved while extracting):
sudo mv gradle-6.6.1 /opt/
And removed the zip
rm gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip
Open vim to edit env variables:
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
Copy into the file and :wq
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle-6.6.1
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
Next time you login to your console

gradle --version

Comment: I don’t have a gradle.properties to change this in.

Comment: If you don't have a `gradle.properties`, then you need to **create** it.